# Postman: Define a variable from list

Tags: postman

I'm using Postman and wondering if I can use a stored JSON object to create variable for additional calls. For an example: I saved an array which include name and ID:

```
[{"id":28,"name":"Action"},{"id":12,"name":"Adventure"},
{"id":16,"name":"Animation"},{"id":35,"name":"Comedy"},
{"id":80,"name":"Crime"},{"id":99,"name":"Documentary"},
{"id":18,"name":"Drama"},{"id":10751,"name":"Family"},
{"id":14,"name":"Fantasy"},{"id":36,"name":"History"},
{"id":27,"name":"Horror"},{"id":10402,"name":"Music"},
{"id":9648,"name":"Mystery"},{"id":10749,"name":"Romance"},
{"id":878,"name":"Science Fiction"},{"id":10770,"name":"TV Movie"},
{"id":53,"name":"Thriller"},{"id":10752,"name":"War"},
{"id":37,"name":"Western"}]
```

I'm triggering another API (second call) that retrieves only IDs, so the response is like this: `"genre_ids": [35, 10402]`

Is there a way to create an environment variable that looks for the IDs, fetch the relevant name from the second API and create a name oriented variable so on the case above `35=comedy` and `10402=music` so the variable will be: `comedy,music`?

Answer (score 0):

to save environment variable you can do the following (see the snippets on the right side of postman):

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("variable_key", "variable_value");
```

if you want to save a global variable just do :

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("variable_key", "variable_value");
```

and then use them as you want.

Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it's possible with "Tests"(or Post-Request) script.

But since you have 2 requests(and Postman force you there should be 2 separated requests) you should save response from first request into variable with setEnvironmentVariable or setGlobalVariable and after getting response for 2nd request - to parse response for first one and iterate over it, looking up by id given.